# Images in NextJS not working when replacing a new image

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js

I try to replace my current banner with any other images to see if they works but any image that I put leads to error when using it using Image from `next/image` and even in just simple `<image>` tag. It says `The requested resource isn't a valid image.` when I go to the url. All images are under of `/public/images`.

Here's the code for Image (the working 1)

```
    <Image
       src={"/banner.png"}
       alt="Image"
       layout="fill"
       objectFit="contain"
    />
```

But when I change the /banner.png into new name (ofcourse existing image too under the /public/images/), it just error with code 400 on request.

Comment: Can you show us the code for the non-working image, and also your `public` folder structure?

Answer (score -1):

Try this in src:

src="/banner.png"

instead of src={"/banner.png"}

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).